# str(1) returning with a space in front excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

In an excel program, I was debugging when I noticed that the string function of a number returned the number but with a space in front of it: `str(1)` returned `" 1"`.

As far as I am aware, there is nothing much on the internet about this, so I would appreciate knowing whether it is a glitch, or if I am doing something wrong. There is a way of working around, if this may help:

`Mid(Str(1), 2, 1)` So what this does is take the second character of `" 1"`, and if the number is 5 characters long, for example, change the number at the end to 5 eg `Mid(Str(11111), 2, 5)`.

Thanks for any feedback, however, with the work-around, it is not 100% necessary that this question is answered.

If it helps, I use office 365...

Comment: By the way, you could use `LTrim()` instead of `Mid()` (`LTrim`'s very purpose is to get rid of leading spaces). However, maybe the better function to use would be `CStr()` instead of `Str()`, as `CStr()` does not include a leading space when converting numbers.

Answer (score 4):

From the VBA Reference:

*When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always reserved for the sign of number. If number is positive, the returned string contains a leading space and the plus sign is implied. Use the Format function to convert numeric values you want formatted as dates, times, or currency or in other user-defined formats. Unlike Str, the Format function doesn't include a leading space for the sign of number.*

Please see:

[Str Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/str-function)

Answer (score 0):

The leading space provided by VBA's Str function to positive numbers is for alignment purposes.

Text/strings are by default left-aligned on the worksheet. Since negative numbers receive a hyphen, positive numbers receive a space to maintain alignment.

Btw, if you omit VBA's Mid function's third argument (number of characters), all remaining characters from the second argument's starting position are returned. This means that `Mid(Str(<any number>), 2)` will always return the full number although any negative number's sign would be omitted. This does not work with the worksheet's MID function.